# How to select n rows such as the values of one given column are all distinct?

Tags: r, dplyr

Good afternoon!

Assume I have the following matrix :

```
 Sensor location  Target location detection Probability
1                 7              13             0.2943036
2                21              15             0.2943036
3                16              13             0.2943036
4                18              15             0.2943036
5                21              15             0.2943036
6                 1               2             0.2943036
7                16              22             0.2943036
8                10               4             0.2943036
9                16              17             0.2943036
10                2               5             0.2943036
11               13              16             0.2943036
12                9              12             0.2943036
13                2               8             0.2943036
14                7               1             0.2943036
15                7              10             0.2943036
16                1               2             0.2943036
17               18              12             0.2943036
18               23              17             0.2943036
19               21              15             0.2943036
20               20              21             0.2943036
21                2               1             0.2943036
22               12              18             0.2943036
23               24              21             0.2943036
24               22              23             0.2943036
25                2               3             0.2943036
26               11              10             0.2943036
27                7              10             0.2943036
28                2               3             0.2943036
29               12               6             0.2943036
30                2               1             0.2943036
31               24              21             0.2943036
32               14               8             0.2943036
```

How can I sample from this matrix n rows such as **the values of the second column are all distinct**?

Example of desired output ( The `Target location` column values must be unique ):

with n=4 :

```
         Sensor location  Target location detection Probability 
4                18              15             0.2943036
7                16              22             0.2943036
8                10               4             0.2943036
9                16              17             0.2943036
```

Undesired output ( The value `15` is present more than once in the second column ) :

```
      Sensor location  Target location detection Probability 
4                18              15             0.2943036
2                21              15             0.2943036
8                10               4             0.2943036
9                16              17             0.2943036
```

I know that `dplyr` has functions like `sample_n()` and `dplyr::distinct`, I had tried :

```
data %>% distinct("Target location")
```

I hope my question is clear, Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: If you do ```dput(data)``` (where data is the name of your data.frame), and copy paste the output in the question it gives us a reproducible example. 
That being said, if it is correct in your case to first make sure that the second column is unique and then sample. Then you can get a matrix from which to draw your sample with: ```sample_data <- data %>% distinct(`Target location`, .keepall = TRUE)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
n <- 25
indicesToSampleFrom <- which(!duplicated(data[["Target location"]]))
data[sample(indicesToSampleFrom,n),]
```

Edit: If you want to apply this logic to other columns, it would be nice to check whether there are enough ditstinct values. So instead of sampling `n` rows, sample `min(n,length(indicesToSampleFrom))`.

Comment: yes this solved the question. Thank you a lot!